# Использование коллекции структур

Tags: c#, коллекции

Есть такая структура.

```
  struct action2 { public string a; public string b;}
```

Такое выражение спокойно работает.

```
action2 p = new action2();   
p.a = "eee";   
p.b = "eee";
```

А такое не хочет

```
List<action2> u = new List<action2>();
 u.Add(new action2());
 u.Add(new action2());
 u.Add(new action2());

 u[0].a = "gggg";
```

Пишет  
Не удалось изменить возвращаемое значение для `"System.Collections.Generic.List<kitay.HandAction.Move>.this[int]"`, т.к. оно не является переменной

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что action2 - это struct, то есть значимый тип. Поэтому, обращаясь к u[0] вы получаете только его копию, а не ссылку на него. Копия переменной не является, и изменять ее поля/свойства вы не можете. Можете только изменить его целиком. Например так:
    u[0] = new action2()

а вообще, уважаемый [@alex91](/users/10388/alex91), как вам не стыдно - информации по этой ошибке в гугле тонны. Ай-ай-ай

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Согласен, но находил что-то близкое к этому, но не совсем то.

Comment: вот еще тут почитайте об этом: http://habrahabr.ru/post/124404/